# Coroutine launch doesn't work inside lambda

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a piece of code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val requestLooper = RequestLooper()
    val messageParser = MessageParser(
        onStart = { chatId ->
            println("On text")
            launch {
                println("Enter coroutine")
                requestLooper.start(chatId)
            }
            println("On text exit")
        },
        onStop = { chatId -> requestLooper.stop(chatId) }
    )
}
```

In this code I launch a new coroutine on each lambda call.

The output of this code is:

```
On text
On text exit
```

As you can see, launch simply doesn't work. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I cannot just launch coroutine from lambda. I need to create a scope and use it inside lambda. Like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(this.coroutineContext + SupervisorJob())

    val requestLooper = RequestLooper()
    val messageParser = MessageParser(
        onStart = { chatId ->
            scope.launch {
                requestLooper.start(chatId)
            }
        },
        onStop = { chatId -> requestLooper.stop(chatId) }
    )
}
```

The important parts are:

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(this.coroutineContext + SupervisorJob())
...
scope.launch {
...
```

Comment: Oups, my bad. Fixed it. Thank you for pointing it out